# How to style elements within other elements with css?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way with css to add a certain style only to elements within a certain other element? For example: the textareas within a certain div element would have a certain style, but other textareas would not have that style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

```
div.your-style > textarea{
   height: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Since the OP is apparently new to CSS, it should be noted that this only works for textareas that are a *direct* child of the div, and won't work if they are, for example, wrapped in a label or another div: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/childselector. The OP may need a simple [descendant selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/descendantselector) instead.

Answer (score 2):

html:

```
<div id="dv1">
    <div class="dv2"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#dv1{ ... }
.dv2{ ... }
#dv1 .dv2{ ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this for example:

```
div.classname textarea
{
    // css
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="xxx"

<div class="yyy"

css:

#xxx{  anything with id xxx
}

.yyy{   anything  with class yyy
}

div{   all div(s)
}

div.yyy{   the div with class yyy
}

div #xxx{   the div's sub element with id xxx
}

 div .yyy{   the div's sub element with class yyy
}

.yyy div{  any div inside a element with class yyy
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.foo textarea {
    color: red;
}
```

That changes the font color of all text areas inside elements with a class `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

For all textareas

```
textarea{color:black}
```

For certain textarea inside a div with id 'mydiv'

```
#mydiv > textarea{color:red}
```

For certain textarea inside a div with class 'mydiv'

```
.mydiv > textarea{color:gray}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without or without the new CSS selector, which is ->
either `.yourclass img{}` or `.yourclass->img{}` will do the same thing.